# Malloc crash when trying to load a linked list

Tags: c, string, linked-list, malloc, fgets

I'm trying to initialize a linked list from a text file, here are my structs :

```
typedef struct Diagnostic
{
    char* disease;
    int priority;
}Diagnostic;

typedef struct Fiche Fiche;
struct Fiche
{
    char* name;
    int age;
    Diagnostic diagnostic;

    Fiche* next; // because this is a linked list
};
```

And this is my load function :

```
void loadFiches()
{
    int i;
    char tmp1[100], tmp2[100];
    Fiche* current;
    FILE* file = fopen("fiches.txt", "r");

    if(file != NULL)
    {
        while(!feof(file))
        {
            printf("malloc:");
            current = malloc(sizeof(Fiche)); // allocate memory for a new fiche
            printf("%p\n", current);

            fgets(tmp1, 100, file); // get the name
            cleanChar(tmp1); // remove '\n'

            fscanf(file, "%d\n", &current->age); // get the age

            fgets(tmp2, 100, file); // get the disease
            cleanChar(tmp2); // remove '\n'

            fscanf(file, "%d\n", &current->diagnostic.priority); // get the priority

            current->diagnostic.disease = malloc(strlen(tmp2) * sizeof(char)); // allocate memory for the disease
            strcpy(current->diagnostic.disease, tmp2); // copy the disease in the corresponding field

           // Then I add this fiche to my linked list
        }

    }
    else printf("error");

    fclose(file);
}
```

The output of this is

```
malloc:00350FD8
malloc:00350FF8
malloc:
```

So it crashes at the third malloc. Note that I only initialize the disease field because that is the one causing the crash, everything else works fine so it doesn't appear in this code.
Also note that in debug mode everything works totally fine.

And if I remove `cleanChar(tmp2);` or `strcpy(current->diagnostic.disease, tmp2);`, then it works fine too (but I have an unwanted \n in the first case), it's the combination of the two lines that causes the crash.

Here is my cleanChar function :

```
void cleanChar(char string[100])
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
        if(string[i] == '\n') string[i] = '\0';
}
```

Does anyone have an Idea on what could cause the crash ? I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the way I save my fiches to the text file but here is the save function :

```
void saveFiches(List list)
{
    int i;
    Fiche* current = list.first;
    FILE* file;

        file = fopen("fiches.txt", "w+");

        if(file != NULL)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < list.size; i++)
            {
                fprintf(file, "%s\n%d\n%s\n%d\n", current->name, current->age, current->diagnostic.disease, current->diagnostic.priority);
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
        else printf("error");

        fclose(file);
}
```

`List` is a struct that contains the first element of my linked list.

Comment: `malloc(strlen(tmp2) * sizeof(char))` -> `malloc(strlen(tmp2) + 1)` (you need room for the terminating `'\0'`).

Comment: Note that your title is misleading, you could think that it's `malloc()`'s fault but it's not. The problem is somewhere else, perhapse where the comment above points out, but not with `malloc()`.

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: So it is `malloc((strlen(tmp2)+1) * sizeof(char))` but that fixed it. Thank you. Try to write an answer so I can put this thread to solved

Comment: @Drakalex Note that `sizeof(char)` MUST be 1 and it's mandated by the c standard.

Comment: Use `strdup()` to help avoid problems like this in the future (and make the code a bit easier to read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string `malloc()` is off by one (you don't consider the terminating `'\0'`:

```
current->diagnostic.disease = malloc(strlen(tmp2) * sizeof(char));
```

should be:

```
current->diagnostic.disease = malloc((strlen(tmp2) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

and, since `sizeof(char)` is always `1` this could be:

```
current->diagnostic.disease = malloc(strlen(tmp2) + 1);
```

unless you want to make the `malloc()` more robust by dereferencing the pointer it gets assigned to in order to determine the appropriate size:

```
current->diagnostic.disease = malloc((strlen(tmp2) + 1) *
  sizeof(*(current->diagnostic.disease)));
```

You could also duplicate the string:

```
current->diagnostic.disease = strdup(tmp2);
```

Whichever way you do it, don't forget to check the result for `NULL`